# Git e GitHub: Precisa dar remote mais de uma vez?

Tags: git, github

Quando eu vou fazer o procedimento para dar upar os arquivos do meu diretório para o GitHub, por meio do Git, eu preciso dar `git remote add origin ...` a cada vez ou só a primeira vez basta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando `git remote add origin` geralmente se usa apenas uma vez para cada repositório remoto, feito isso a configuração do remote fica salva em seu repositório local.Pode usar o comando: `git remote -v` para mostrar os repositórios remotos configurados.

Comment: Muito obrigado!